# AngularJS - Error: Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on youtube

**Asp.net MVC 6 web api with angular js**:
[Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2er6mMglRVg)

But now half way through the tutorial I've run into a problem

The error I get in the browser console is:

*angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: QuotesProvider <- Quotes <- quotesController*

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Quotes App</title>

    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    
    <div ng-controller="quotesController">
        <h2>List of Quotes</h2>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
                <p>"{{quote.Content}}" - {{quote.Author}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [
        // Angular modules 
        'ngRoute',

        // Custom modules 
        "quotesService"

        // 3rd Party Modules
        
    ]);

})();
```

**quotesController.js**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('quotesController', quotesController);

    quotesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Quotes']; 

    function quotesController($scope, Quotes) {

        $scope.quotes = Quotes.query();
    }
})();
```

**quotesService.js**

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var quotesService = angular.module('quotesService', ['ngResource']);

    quotesService.factory('Quotes', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

        return $resource('/api/quotes/', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });

    }]);
})();
```

QuotesController.cs (ASP.NET)

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApp.models;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace MyApp.api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class QuotesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Quote> Get()
        {
            return new List<Quote> {
                new Quote {Id = 1, Content = "Happy Happy Happy", Author = "Leonardo DiCaprio" },
                new Quote {Id = 2, Content = "Smile to life and life smiles back at you", Author = "Liam Bison" },
                new Quote {Id = 3, Content = "You are your own Happy Blacksmith", Author = "Joyce Cammi" }
            };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping you guys could help me find the error. I'm quite new at Angular and other answers I've found didn't seem to help me.

Comment: i dont see the quotes js file used.

Comment: Are you actually loading `quotesController.js`? It doesn't look like it based on your example... Add this to the `<head>` tag: `<script src="quotesController.js"></script>`

Comment: In the tutorial he doesn't link to the quotesController.js and it works for him - But I've now tried where I link to it and still gives the same error

Comment: @Jotothehan, if you do not add the script tag as Todd Miller said, angular will not know about quotesController. Its like any other javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is essentially complaining that it can't locate the function you declared or its parameters. In this case, it is complaining that it cannot inject Quotes. The first issue I can see is that you have not required ngResource in your app. This would cause a failure to instantiate the controller, and most likely trigger this unknown provider error. You can read all about it in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Try this in app.js:

```
angular.module('app', [
        // Angular modules 
        'ngRoute',

//////////////////
        'ngResource',
///////////////insert this ^^^^

        // Custom modules 
        "quotesService"

        // 3rd Party Modules

    ])
```

Comment: That seemed to work - I'm not getting any errors in console now - It's not loading any quotes, but that could be another error :)